# Extract HTML content from string in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea, inside this textarea, dynamic HTML content are bind like

```
<div id="HDWebAllTemplateHTMLListMessage">
    <div id="header">This is a header</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div id="content">This is my main content.</div>
      <div id="sidebar">This is a sidebar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">This is my footer</div>
</div>
```

Somehow i want html content inside ***.main*** class.  I tried but not able to get html content.

```
var textAreaContent=$($('#HDWebAllTemplateHTMLListMessage').text());
var divContent=textAreaContent.find('.main');
console.log(divContent.innerHTML);
```

Comment: `#HDWebAllTemplateHTMLListMessage` is nowhere in the code you posted, nor is `.23TC`, and what is `htmlContent`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance i have update my question

Comment: @Anjyr But what is `#HDWebAllTemplateHTMLListMessage`?

Comment: jQuery's `find()` function returns a jQuery object, and it doesn't have a property named `innerHTML`, use `html()` instead. Also, jQuery's `text()` function doesn't returns the HTML tags - again, use `html()` instead. See [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use textarea?

You can try like below. But if you don't need it. The azizsagi example is working fine.

JAVASCRIPT

```
var newdiv1 = $("<div class='dummy'></div>");
$("textarea").after(newdiv1); /* create dummy div */
var tgt = newdiv1;
var main = tgt.html($("textarea").text()).find(".main").text();
tgt.text(main);
/* newdiv1.remove(); */ // If you want to remove the element after you get what you need
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/amgtLwex/

Answer (score 0):

`text()` gives you the text content, not the html, so it won't work to wrap it in `$()`. Use `html()`.

`$('#HDWebAllTemplateHTMLListMessage .main').html()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result by changing your js script to follows

```
<script>
var textAreaContent=$('#HDWebAllTemplateHTMLListMessage > .main').html();
console.log(textAreaContent);
</script>
```

here is running example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="HDWebAllTemplateHTMLListMessage">
    <div id="header">This is a header</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div id="content">This is my main content.</div>
      <div id="sidebar">This is a sidebar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">This is my footer</div>
</div>
<script>
var textAreaContent=$('#HDWebAllTemplateHTMLListMessage > .main').html();
console.log(textAreaContent);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```